# ステガノグラフィについて

Tags: security

現在、画像にデータを埋め込む”ステガノグラフィ”について調べています。
とある論文を読んでいたところ、以下のような記述を見つけました。

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4655281&tag=1

> - ”マスキングを用いる手法では、LSBによる手法に比べて圧縮処理、切り取り、いくつかの画像処理に対してロバストである。(変換処理に対して強い)”
> - "Masking is more robust than LSB insertion with respect to
>     compression, cropping, and some image processing"

この説明がよく理解できていなくて困っております。なぜ、マスキングする処理のほうがLSBに比べてロバストになるのか教えていただけますと幸いです。

Comment: IEEEサイトからの論文入手は有償ですがが、著者自身(Neil F. Johnson, Ph.D.)により公開されている http://www.jjtc.com/pub/r2026a.htm が同じ内容でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

同引用文に続く文書が、そのまま理由説明になっていると思います（強調部は回答者による）。

> Masking techniques **embed information in significant areas** so that the hidden message is more integral to the cover image than just hiding it in the "noise" level. This makes it more suitable than LSB with, for instance, lossy JPEG images.

大雑把に言えば、「LSB(least significant bit) insertion」では画像データの下位ビットに情報を埋め込みますが、「Masking and filtering」では画像データの上位ビットに情報を埋め込みます。

JPEGなどのlossy画像圧縮アルゴリズムは、人間の目では認識しずらい情報、つまり画像データの下位ビットのように“重要度が低い”情報（引用文中では"noise" levelと言及されている部分）から積極的に削減しますから、LSB insertionはロバストではありません。